# Delphi XML Rest Client

Tags: java, xml, json, delphi, jaxb

The [docs say:](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/REST_Client_Library)

> The framework focuses on JSON as the representation format. XML is not explicitly supported.

We've been hastily re-programming our legacy delphi app to a snappy tomcat backend with lots of JAXB classes and using SOAP of all things to push over info into our Delphi frontend.  This is pretty nice in windows, but I'd like to actually use some of the new features in Delphi and not just do things I could have done 10-15 years ago.

So, if JSON is the normal framework, how do I go about supporting XML (implicitly)?

Would it be better to just look into some way of spitting JSON out of my JAXB stuff on the java side?  I really like the XML Bindings, but I'm willing to sacrifice them for something that works in the 21st-and-a-half century.

Comment: Does your backend supply WSDL schema? If so, you can use the WSDL importer to automatically create a binding for your web service. (Go into File->New->Other..., select the WebServices group and start WSDL Importer.)

Comment: What I've been doing (and what works surprisingly well and fast) is to use a WSDL to get XML and using the XML bindings, I import the same XSD in delphi that I import in Java.

Comment: So you are saying you already have a solution? I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

What about use simple json library for delphi like this:

[JSON delphi library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lkjson/)

[Delphi Web Utils](http://sourceforge.net/projects/is-webstart/)

[superobject](https://code.google.com/p/superobject/)

Comment: I'd like to _not_ use JSON, it's pretty apparent that I can use it.